# Two parallely polling tasks on an event driven platform

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am currently working on a server platform, which is based on an event driven architecture. An event should enter the system via a websocket connection, and after some processing the response for it should also leave the system via the same websocket connection. The implementation logic behind the idea is, that if a connection is made to the server, I put it in a while cycle, and await it to send me data until it disconnects. The incoming data is put into a queue, from which a worker thread will pull it out and process it. On the other part, I have created a task, which is polling an outgoing event queue, and if there is an event in the queue, it sends it to the corresponding recipient. Unfortunately my current asyncio logic is flawed, in the way that polling the outgoing event queue blocks the receiving task, and I cannot wrap my head around a way to fix it. Here are some code snippets, which should represent the problem presented above:

#### Starting the websocket server

```py
def run(self, address: str, port: int, ssl_context: ssl.SSLContext = None):
    start_server = websockets.serve(
        self.websocket_connection_handler, address, port, ssl=ssl_context)

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.create_task(self.send_heartbeat())
    event_loop.create_task(self.dispatch_outgoing_events())

    print(f'Running on {"wss" if ssl_context else "ws"}://{address}:{port}')
    event_loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    event_loop.run_forever()
```

#### The dispatcher function which infinitely polls data from the outgoing queue

```py
async def dispatch_outgoing_events(self):
    while not self.exit_state.should_exit:
        if len(self.outgoing_event_queue) == 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
        else:
            event = self.outgoing_event_queue.get_event()
            destination = event.destination
            client_id = re.findall(
                r'[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}', destination)[0]
            client = self.client_store.get(client_id)
            await client.websocket.send(serializer.serialize(event))
```

#### The connection handler function for the websocket

```py
async def websocket_connection_handler(self, websocket, path):
    client_id = await self.register(websocket)

    try:
        while not self.exit_state.should_exit:
            correlation_id = str(uuid4())

            message = await websocket.recv()
            else:
                try:
                    event = serializer.deserialize(
                        message, correlation_id, client_id)
                    event.return_address = f'remote://websocket/{client_id}'
                    self.incoming_event_queue.add_event(event)
                except Exception as e:
                    event = type('evt', (object,), dict(system_entry=str(
                        datetime.datetime.utcnow()), destination=f'remote://websocket/{client_id}'))()

                    self.exception_handler.handle_exception(
                        e, event)

    except Exception as exception:
        print(
            f'client {client_id} suddenly disconnected. Reason: {type(exception).__name__} -> {exception}')
        self.client_store.remove(client_id)
        self.topic_factory.remove_client(client_id)
        self.topic_factory.get_topic('server_notifications').publish(ClientDisconnectedNotification(client_id),
                                                                        str(uuid4()))
```

Comment: Please clarify what issue you are actually having. As in, what is your *question*?

Comment: What do you think is the blocking call in your dispatcher function?  I don't see one.  Are you sure that is your actual problem?  Have you tried making the argument to the asyncio,sleep call in the dispatcher some value like 0.1?  You need some print statements or logging function calls to figure this out.